# Converting text from CSV into SQL image data

Tags: sql, ssis, type-conversion

I have a data that is being extracted from a SQL image datatype into a CSV, then transfered to us via SFTP, and I need to get it back into a image data type. When I try to convert via SSIS I get a buffer overflow message. Is it possible to take a text data stream and convert it into a SQL Image data type?

Comment: can we see the code you are executing?

Comment: I'm confused. Is the CSV a file with only one record in it? I would think the binary nature of the data would pooch the format. Could you expand on the mechanics of how you're exporting and then re-importing the data?